# Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, data-binding, thymeleaf

Trying to change value inside my model class which contains a private String name and I wanted to change the name using Thymeleaf in HTML page then see the change in another url response body.

When I try to access my ("/myname") page in localhost I got the error: 
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'

Here is my Model:

```
public class Name {

    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/name")
    @ResponseBody 
    public String showName() {
        Name myname = new Name();
        return myname.getName();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/myname")
    public String setName() {
        return "myname";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "myname", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showName(@ModelAttribute Name iko, BindingResult errors, Model model) {
        return "name";
    }   
}
```

Here is my html thymeleaf pages:
myname.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/myname}" th:object="${iko}" method="post">
    <label>Enter the name</label><br/>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry to forget to add the model.addAttribute inside the controller functions and by doing that the error mentioned in the title has gone but I have another problem that the Value of the data I wanted to change isnt changing

Comment: My question is: working with Thymeleaf engine, do we only retrieve our model data using Thymeleaf? because I cannot use normal getter to check the changed model value. I see Null in the rquested URL /name